# Is there a phrase for "something good that doesn't last long"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, equivalence

In Arabic, the expression "Summer cloud" is usually used to mean that "this is not going to last for a long time" or "it won't last as long as you think it will".

Is there an equivalent phrase in English?

Comment: I think you misled people into concentrating on "doesn't last long” at the expense of the full phrase. Either that, or the "something good" was in itself misleading. Could you provide a full translation, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**short-lived**

[American Heritage dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=short-lived&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

> Living or lasting only a short time; ephemeral.

I'll try to find something with more of a connotation of positivity.

---

You could use: "that moment was ***like an éclair***"

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89clair#Etymology)

> The word comes from French éclair 'flash of lightning', so named because it is eaten quickly (in a flash).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

'A flash in the pan' and 'one-hit wonder' mean momentary success or something good that doesn't last long.

Also, '15 minutes of fame' means brief success, notoriety, importance etc. The expression was inspired by Andy Warhol's words "In the future, everyone will be world-famous for 15 minutes", which appeared in the program for a 1968 exhibition.